# JS text to array

Tags: javascript, text, formatting

I have this text:

```
2/92/20
3/32/32
4/62/6
5/22/28
6/60/61
7/33/32
8/34/31
9/31/19
10/19/19
11/34/39
12/32/32
14/19/25
15/45/37
16/32/32
17/84/36
18/72/33
```

And I need it to be like:

```
// 2/92/20
chars[0][0]=2;
chars[0][1]=92;
chars[0][2]=20;
```

How can I do that? P.S. The split must be in:

```
$.ajax({   
    type:     "POST",
    url:      "char_info2.php",   
    dataType: "html",  
    success:  function(data) 
              {
                  //here
              }
});
```

Comment: How is the input structured? Is it already in an array? Just a single string with line breaks?

Comment: it can be output like json too but i don't want it because it weight much PS: it's an array

Comment: @Sonny -- "weight much" -- what do you mean by that.  JSON seems like the natural way to send this to the client: `[[2,92,20],[3,32,32]...`

Comment: btw json send only one row when i need to send them all

Comment: @Sonny - then you're doing something wrong constructing your JSON or you're interpreting it incorrectly in the client.

Comment: @Sonny: You mean when you try it to send it as JSON it only sends on row? Then you are doing something wrong on the server side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have one string with line breaks, you can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var chars = str.split("\n");
for(var i = chars.length; i--; ) {
    chars[i] = chars[i].split('/');
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/mzT3t/)

If you want to have them as integers you would have to loop over them again.

But I agree with the comments, sending them as JSON makes much more sense!

Answer (score 2):

You can either use split or a regular expression:

```
var your_text = "2/92/20\n" +
"3/32/32\n" +
// ... etc ...

// Split Version    
var line_by_line = your_text.split("\n");
var final_array = [];
for (var i=0; i < line_by_line.length; i++) {
    final_array.push(line_by_line[i].split("/"));
}

// Regular Expression Version
var splitter = /^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)$/gi;
var final_array = [];
your_text.replace(splitter, function(matched_string, match1, match2, match3) {
    if (match1) { // Assumes 0 is not a valid 1st number
        final_array.push([match1, match2, match3]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split on newline and slash

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp